# Scraping Issue with BeautifulSoup only while using for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python code using the 'BeautifulSoup' library that would pull titles and authors of all the opinion pieces from a news website. While the for loop is working as intended for the titles, the find function within it meant to pull the author's name for each of the titles is repeatedly returning the author of the first piece as the output.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**The Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/international/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

opinion = soup.find('div', class_='css-717c4s')

for story in opinion.find_all('article'):
    title = story.h2.text
    print(title)

    author = opinion.find('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')
    print (author.text)
```

**The Output:**

The Nazi-Fighting Women of the Jewish Resistance
Judy Batalion
My Great-Grandfather Knew How to Fix America’s Food System
Judy Batalion
Old Pol, New Tricks
Judy Batalion
Do We Have to Pay Businesses to Obey the Law?
Judy Batalion
I Don’t Want My Role Models Erased
Judy Batalion
Progressive Christians Arise! Hallelujah!
Judy Batalion
What the 2020s Need: Sex and Romance at the Movies
Judy Batalion
Biden Has Disappeared
Judy Batalion
What Republicans Could Learn From My Grandmother
Judy Batalion
Your Home’s Value Is Based on Racism
Judy Batalion
Once I Am Fully Vaccinated, What Is Safe for Me to Do?
Judy Batalion

Comment: What is the expected output can you pls include that in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do,

```
author = story.find('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')
```

What's wrong is, you are doing

```
author = opinion.find('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')
```

and it fetches the first author in all the authors in the opinions section and since you run this statement in every iteration of the loop, hence no matter how many times you do it, you will only get the first author.

Replacing it with
`author = story.find('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')`
fetches you the first author for each story iteration and since each story has a single author, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you target only the first tag, hence the one author.

Here's a fix for your code using `zip()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/international/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').find('div', class_='css-717c4s')

authors = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')
stories = soup.find_all('article')

for author, story in zip(authors, stories):
    print(author.text)
    print(story.h2.text)
```

Output:

```
Judy Batalion
The Nazi-Fighting Women of the Jewish Resistance
Gracy Olmstead
My Great-Grandfather Knew How to Fix America’s Food System
Maureen Dowd
Old Pol, New Tricks
Nikolas Bowie
Do We Have to Pay Businesses to Obey the Law?
Elizabeth Becker
I Don’t Want My Role Models Erased
Nicholas Kristof
Progressive Christians Arise! Hallelujah!
Ross Douthat
What the 2020s Need: Sex and Romance at the Movies
Frank Bruni
Biden Has Disappeared
Cecilia Gentili
What Republicans Could Learn From My Grandmother
Dorothy A. Brown
Your Home’s Value Is Based on Racism
Linsey Marr, Juliet Morrison and Caitlin Rivers
Once I Am Fully Vaccinated, What Is Safe for Me to Do?
```

Answer (score 0):

Very little mistake.

You're supposed to do a search on each "article"/story object in the loop Not your initial "opinion" object i.e

```
author = story.find('div', class_='css-1xdt15l')
```

This produces the desired output:

```
The Nazi-Fighting Women of the Jewish Resistance
Judy Batalion
My Great-Grandfather Knew How to Fix America’s Food System
Gracy Olmstead
Old Pol, New Tricks
Maureen Dowd
Do We Have to Pay Businesses to Obey the Law?
Nikolas Bowie
I Don’t Want My Role Models Erased
Elizabeth Becker
Progressive Christians Arise! Hallelujah!
Nicholas Kristof
What the 2020s Need: Sex and Romance at the Movies
Ross Douthat
Biden Has Disappeared
Frank Bruni
What Republicans Could Learn From My Grandmother
Cecilia Gentili
Your Home’s Value Is Based on Racism
Dorothy A. Brown
Once I Am Fully Vaccinated, What Is Safe for Me to Do?
Linsey Marr, Juliet Morrison and Caitlin Rivers
```